# Selenium with async/await in JS, find and click on element

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, ecmascript-2017

I'm trying to refactor my tests using Selenium webdriver and Mocha to ES7 with async/await functionality. I have got following piece of code:

```
await loginPage.loginAsAdmin()

/* THIS DOES NOT WORK */
//await layout.Elements.routePageButton().click()

/* THIS DOES WORK */
let a = await layout.Elements.routePageButton()
await a.click()
```

I don't understand why the particular does not work - I get:

```
TypeError: layout.Elements.routePageButton(...).click is not a function
```

Function before click method returns webElement, as you can see:
[image: Returned element]

Layout:

```
routePageButton:  async () => await findVisibleElement('#route_info a')
const findVisibleElement = utils.Methods.Element.findVisible
```

Method:

```
findVisible: async (cssSelector) => {
  let elm = await driver().findElement(by.css(cssSelector))
  return elm
}
```

Comment: `async/await` is part of ES2017, *not* ES2016 (ES7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is misunderstanding that `await` is a language keyword in ES2017 that allows you to block execution of the calling `async` function until a `Promise` returned by an invoked function resolves.

`routePageButton()` returns a `Promise`, and this is why the second syntax above works, as execution is blocked until the `Promise` resolves to a `WebElement` object.

However in the syntax you are using in the first example, the function that it is attempting to `await` on (`click()`) is never called, because a `Promise` does not have a `click()` function.  Note that you have two `await`s in your second syntax, but only one in your first.

To do what you are attempting to do in one line, you would have to do something like:

```
await (await layout.Elements.routePageButton()).click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, apologies that I got this wrong, I'll edit soon.